# How to set background colour of a cell based on another cell in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, background-color

I want to set the background colour of a cell based on the background colour of another cell.

I have a sheet with days and the corresponding weekdays as text. With the help of conditional formatting I was able to set the background colour of all weekend-days to grey. But now I want to set the background colour of the corresponding day also to grey.

For example, I gave the range in row A a name like days and the range in row B a name like weekdays:

```
row A: day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7
row B: Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun
```

The cells Sat and Sun have a grey background.

I tried to create a script which indicates if the background colour of a cell in row B is grey and sets the same cell in row A also to background colour grey. I know I have to use the function `getBackgroundColor` and `setBackgroundColor`, but I don't know how I can go from cell to cell. And how I can set the same cell in another row?

Answer (score -1):

My range always starts at D2 that´s why I use hard coded numbers at some points. And I preferred to compare the day instead of the color. So here is my solution.

```
function colorWeekends() {

       var getlastcolumn = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getLastColumn();  

      for (var i = 4; i <= getlastcolumn; ++i) {
        var activecell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, i);
        var text =activecell.getValue();

        if (text == "Sun" || text == "Sat") {
          var column = activecell.getColumnIndex();
          var row = activecell.getRowIndex();
          var lastrow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow(); 
          var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, column, lastrow);
          SpreadsheetApp.getActive().setActiveRange(range).setBackgroundColor("#efefef");
        }

      }

    }
```